# Image not rendering Active Admin and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin

I am trying to render an image via paperclip like so in Active Admin

```
column "Images" do |m|
  m.member_images.each do |img|
    image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
  end
end
```

but in my view I get this rather than the image itself

```
[#<MemberImage id: 2, member_id: 2, created_at: "2014-02-18 21:37:27", updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:37:27", photo_file_name: "associations.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 140780, photo_updated_at: "2014-02-18 21:37:27">]
```

My Models are set up like so

```
class MemberImage < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :member
has_attached_file :photo, styles: { thumb: '100x100#' }
end


class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :member_images, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :member_images, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Would there be any reason why the image would not show?

Comment: Are you outputting the image code with `<%=` ?

Comment: no as using formtastic within Active Admin, dont use <%=

Comment: ive got it working, and posted the answer @RichPeck but unsure why this works :-)

Answer (score 1):

So after some more looking around on here i have found that this works

```
column "Images" do |m|
 ul do 
   m.member_images.each do |img|
     li do
      image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
    end
   end
 end
end
```

Though i am not sure why this makes a difference

Comment: It's probably your rendering engine that's having a bad day with the `image_tag` helper :D